# ArrayList consisting of JButtons. But doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, netbeans, jbutton

I'm on a project right now and I'm trying out some new code to make my program more efficient. I was thinking of an `ArrayList` "dice" which will contain some buttons (that're supposed to be dice). If I for example `array.add(die1)`, I assume I can refer to the object in the array instead of the actual button.

For example: I can set the text of die1 as `die1.setText("");` I would also like to do it to the object in the array directly so I can use loops, like, `array.get(i).setText("")`;

But it doesn't work which is weird. If I do `array.get(0).getClass()` it says `javax.Swing.JButton` which seems to be right.

Java 11

```
ArrayList dice = new ArrayList<JButton>();


private void die1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (die1.getBackground() == Color.red) {

        dice.remove(dice.indexOf(die1));
        die1.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
    else {
        dice.add(die1);
        die1.setBackground(Color.red);            
    }
}     

private void btnRollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    for (int i = 0; i < dice.size(); i++) {

        int random = roll();

        dice.get(i).setText(""+random); //This displays as error; uncompilable

    }
}
```

Expected: to work.
But naturally it can't compile and crashes.

Comment: How does it crash if it can't compile?  And can you tell us the error message?

Comment: please correctly format your code ;)

Comment: It's because you're not using generics, so you need to cast `dice.get(i)` to whatever type of object you want, ie. a JButton, e.g.  `JButton b = (JButton)dice.get(i);`

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.  The compiler will tell you what’s wrong with `ArrayList dice = new ArrayList<JButton>();`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't typed the declaration of your List.

Try this:

```
List<JButton> dice = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Geez, thanks. >,<
Does it also work in this way from the other comment: 
    `(JButton)dice.get(i);` if I hadn't declared the object type?

Comment: @psisis Unnecessary casting is frowned upon!

Comment: @psisis If this answer has helped you, can you please accept it so the question is marked as closed